# Problem with configuring crystal report XI with postgre database

Tags: postgresql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

We are using Crystal Report XI with DB2 data base for our Application .Now we have new request to develop a report from some other application which has postgre data base.

So same thing we tried with postgre data base that what we did in DB2 data base.

We installed the postgre odbc driver and Test the connection was successfull. But when i tried open from crystal report design, I dont find postgre data source in the list.

What are all the steps needs to do, to connect Crystal Report XI with Postgre database?

Please help me what I am missing here.

Thanks,
Naveen

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you configured a 64-bit ODBC DSN.
Crystal is a 32-bit application.
You need to configure a 32-bit DSN.